# How to find the interpolation polynomial of the DES S-boxes

Tags: aes, des

The Lagrange interpolation polynomial of the AES S-box has degree 254 and 9 terms in it. How about the DES S-boxes? How can we calculate the interpolation polynomial for S-boxes having a different number of input and output bits?

Answer (score 3):

You can use any finite field $\mathbb F_{2^n}$ with $2^n$ elements as long as $n$ is at least the maximum of the bitlengths of the in- and output. If in- or output is too short, one can simply extend it with zeros. For the DES one often takes simply $n=6$.

If you define $\mathbb F_{64}$ as $\mathbb F_2[X]/(X^6+X+1)$ (i.e., use $0x43$ where $0x11b$ is used in the [definition of the field for the AES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard#The_MixColumns_step)), you'll get for the first S-box

[14,  4,  13,  1,   2, 15,  11,  8,
     3, 10,   6, 12,   5,  9,   0,  7,
     0, 15,   7,  4,  14,  2,  13,  1,
    10,  6,  12, 11,   9,  5,   3,  8,
     4,  1,  14,  8,  13,  6,   2, 11,
    15, 12,   9,  7,   3, 10,   5,  0,
    15, 12,   8,  2,   4,  9,   1,  7,
     5, 11,   3, 14,  10,  0,   6, 13]

the polynomial

$$0x31\cdot X^{62} + 0x19\cdot X^{61} + 0x29\cdot X^{60} + 0x09\cdot X^{59} + 0x0d\cdot X^{58} + 0x02\cdot X^{57} + 0x2f\cdot X^{56} + 0x15\cdot X^{55} + 0x3e\cdot X^{54} + 0x05\cdot X^{53} + 0x3d\cdot X^{52} + 0x27\cdot X^{51} + 0x18\cdot X^{50} + 0x35\cdot X^{49} + 0x39\cdot X^{48} + 0x3e\cdot X^{47} + 0x15\cdot X^{46} + 0x37\cdot X^{45} + 0x19\cdot X^{44} + 0x2c\cdot X^{43} + 0x21\cdot X^{42} + 0x32\cdot X^{41} + 0x21\cdot X^{40} + 0x06\cdot X^{39} + 0x17\cdot X^{38} + 0x1b\cdot X^{37} + 0x1d\cdot X^{36} + 0x1a\cdot X^{35} + 0x18\cdot X^{34} + 0x38\cdot X^{33} + 0x23\cdot X^{32} + 0x0a\cdot X^{31} + 0x0f\cdot X^{30} + 0x23\cdot X^{29} + 0x06\cdot X^{27} + 0x1e\cdot X^{26} + 0x3a\cdot X^{25} + 0x38\cdot X^{24} + 0x1e\cdot X^{23} + 0x3c\cdot X^{22} + 0x2b\cdot X^{21} + 0x31\cdot X^{20} + 0x2f\cdot X^{19} + 0x21\cdot X^{17} + 0x20\cdot X^{16} + 0x0b\cdot X^{15} + 0x18\cdot X^{14} + 0x2b\cdot X^{13} + 0x04\cdot X^{12} + 0x19\cdot X^{11} + 0x16\cdot X^{10} + 0x11\cdot X^{9} + 0x26\cdot X^{8} + 0x1f\cdot X^{7} + 0x0e\cdot X^{6} + 0x36\cdot X^{5} + 0x04\cdot X^{4} + 0x33\cdot X^{3} + 0x17\cdot X^{2} + 0x3e\cdot X + 0x0e$$